# Adding dynmaic debugging info to makefile, from the command-line

Tags: makefile

Any ideas how to add dynamic debugging info from the command-line?

For example, given a Makefile:

```
override MAKEFLAGS=r

ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0)

0::
    @$(MAKE)

else

1::
    @echo $(foo)

endif
```

I want to define from the command-line, like this:

```
make foo='$@'
```

So, that it will echo the command that is being executed.

But, i always get:

```
0
```

Where the target executed in the recursive make, is '**1**'.

Comment: In Make 3.81, this works if I remove the `override` directive. I don't know why that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following either in an included makefile, or within a makefile itself:

```
ifeq ("$(DEBUG)","1")
D :=
DBGECHO = @echo
else
D := @
DBGECHO = @true
endif
```

Then, in your makefile, you can have a rule like

```
foo: xxx
     $(DBGECHO) "building $@"
     $(D)$(MAKE) -C $@
```

if you do `make foo`, you won't get any output, but if you do `make foo DEBUG=1`, then you would get

```
building foo
make -C foo
```

As far as passing  `$@` to the makefile via a variable, make expands `$(foo)`, but will not expand the contents of $(foo) afterwards (it's done its substitution).   You can use `eval` to do things like that.